# install glmnet in python

Tags: python, glmnet

Is it possible to install glmnet in python 2 or 3 (windows machine):

Using this:

```
 conda install glmnet
```

produces this error:

```
 packages not found error: ... not available from current channels
```

Does anyone experience similar problems?

edit: Using pip gave me this error:

```
failed with error code 1
```

Comment: What have you already tried to resolve this? What operating system are you on, Windows xp, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10, ect? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I am not sure what alternatives I should try, thus the above is all I have to offer so far. I am using Windows 7, I experience the same problem on Win 10. 64 bit both.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Comment: On one machine, yes. I have 2 and 3. On the other I have only 3

Answer (score 2):

According to the anaconda cloud website [glmnet package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/glmnet) the available version for mac and Ubuntu users. It's not available yet for Windows users. The only way is to install the r version of it with anaconda [r-glmnet](https://anaconda.org/r/r-glmnet).

```
conda install -c r r-glmnet
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/civisanalytics/python-glmnet) says you should install using either:

`conda install -c conda-forge glmnet`

or

`pip install glmnet`

EDIT:

It seems there are multiple "glmnet" packages for python that go by different names. Here is another: https://github.com/conda-forge/r-glmnet-feedstock

To install that one you just do:

`conda install -c conda-forge r-glmnet`

Either way, the key is to specify which channel you want to install from using the `-c` flag followed by the channel name (`conda-forge`), and then the correct name for the package you want

Alternatively, instead of specifying the channel name every time you want to install something, you can add `conda-forge` to your config with:

`conda config --add channels conda-forge`

Then you no longer need to use `-c` and can just install packages with:

`conda install r-glmnet`

or `conda install glmnet`

Comment: I have tried both for conda, and get the same error.

Comment: for pip I have used the command you suggest, I also tried glmnet_py

Comment: See my edit. I found another glmnet package and not sure which one you actually want. But the key to installing anything from conda forge is to specify the channel name with `-c`

Comment: So the other glmnet package works, that is r-glmnet. But for glmnet I still get the same error even after adding the channel forge

Comment: However, I cannot import r-glmnet, due to the dash I am getting a syntax error

Comment: Using this:  foobar = __import__("r-glmnet") tells me there is not package called r-glmnet

Comment: It says here that the conda package is only for linux and osx:https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/glmnet

Comment: yeah its possible thats the reason why you cant install it on the Windows platform. Sorry I cant be of much help - Im not familiar with that specific package

Comment: I see, thank you so much still for your help though Simon, highly appreciated!! I found a way to do what I was trying to do in scikit learns elastic net, so I think I will just stick to that.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I succeeded:

1. You need a fortran compiler. If you're a student (like me), you can get it from intel for free: https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software/student
2. Clone the repo for https://pypi.org/project/glmnet/ from https://github.com/civisanalytics/python-glmnet.
3. Launch the fortran compiler environment in a command prompt
4. Navigate to the folder where you cloned the repo
5. Activate the conda environment you want to install glmnet into
6. Run `python setup.py install`

The package will now be available as `glmnet_python`